# ATI Radeon HD 5770 resolution issues

Tags: macos, gpu

I have a new MacPro5,1 running 10.6 with the ATI Radeon HD 5770 graphics card... Today I was using it and the resolution just shrunk to 1680x1050 and thats as high as it will go.  I also get "formatBus" errors when running several programs? (Shake,Etc)

Any idea whats going on?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried resetting the PRAM?
Also run the Apple Hardware Test to see if it comes up with any GPU errors.